# How to replace the dots in this slider with slide index number with the same formatting?

Tags: javascript, slider

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_quotes_slideshow

Trying to replace the dots in this slider with slide index number with the same formatting. How can we do it? Please help I am a newbie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit the html directly to add the numbers in:

```
<div class="dot-container">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)">1</span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)">2</span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)">3</span> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @jessh. It helped.  I appreciate